# ASP.Net WebMethod 405

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, webmethod

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on why I may be receiving a 405 errors on my ASP.Net VB.Net WebMethod when attemping to call from JQuery ajax method.

Server Implementation:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function DoSomething(id As String) As String
        Dim vm As HssViewModel = New HssViewModel()

        Dim jResult As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm)

        Return jResult
   End Function
```

Javscript Implementation:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mypage.aspx/DoSomething",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            data: { 'id': 'ABC12345' },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: true,
            succes: function (data) {
                context = data;
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {

                console.log("JQUERY ERROR RESPONSE: " + err.message);
            }
        });
```

I am consistently receiving the following error message:

```
POST http://localhost/mypage.aspx/DoSomething 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I have also tried setting up the script method tag to allow a GET request but then I receive a 404

```
  <ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
```

Answer (score 1):

Your WebMethod is expecting a GET request:

```
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True
```

but you are doing a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
```

A 405 is thrown by IIS when an HTTP verb(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD,etc.) is requested and is not supported/disallowed by the designated handler.

If after changing the discrepancy above the problem persist then look at your iis handler mappings.

Comment: Sorry yes I tried both post and get, that was left over code.  When I was unable to successfully POST I implemented ScriptMethod attribute to try and allow GET request.

Comment: @tafaju did you try to look at iis andler mappings?

Comment: I did but this is running in webdev vs2012 and configurations settings did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines to your web.config. I had this problem after deploying to a web server but did not experience while debugging locally. This goes in the  section.

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```