# Posting json to WebService

Tags: c#, json, ajax, web-services

I want to pass json object to a [WebMethod].

My [WebMethod] looks like this;

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void UpdateBooksOrder(Success succ)
{
    try
    {
        if (succ != null)
        {                            
            updateDal.LogSGDetails(succ);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("exception ", ex);
    }
}
```

And, I get [WebMethod] URL as;

```
http://localhost:50596/OrderStatusUpdate.asmx?op=UpdateBooksOrder
```

For testing, I am passing a json object to above [WebMethod] using html+ajax like this;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnUpdate").live("click", function () {
        //alert("OK");
            var succ = {};
            succ.id = "1";
            succ.refrerence = "148997";
            succ.external_ref = "GF0000148997";
            succ.status = "1";
            succ.status_name = "test";          

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:50596/OrderStatusUpdate.asmx?op=UpdateBooksOrder',
                data: "{succ:" + JSON.stringify(succ) + "}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I run the WebService project and call it via html I get following error;

```
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Please guide me a way to resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in below way. It works fine. 
Web service

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string OrderstatusUpdate(OrderStatus orderStatus)
    {
       //do what ever
        return "Success";
    }
```

OrderStatus Class

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

Java script

```
function resolveObject(data) {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty('d')) return data;
        else return data.d;
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({ "contentType": "application/json;charset=utf-8", "dataType": "json", "error": function (e) { console.log(e); return; } });

    function saveOrder() {


        var a = { orderStatus: {} };
        a.orderStatus.Id = 1;
        a.orderStatus.Reference = "reference";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../services/OrderService.asmx/OrderstatusUpdate",
            data: JSON.stringify(a),
            success: function (r) {
                alert(resolveObject(r));
            }
        });

    }
```

And make sure you have uncommented the following line right before the Web service class

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [WebMethod] attribute is typically for older xml web services.

What type of project is this?  If this is a newer project, please look into using the newer constructs like [HttpPost].  Can you post up the request to further investigation (using fiddler)?

Comment: Also, take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101621/asp-net-webmethod-405

Comment: Yes, this is an older application using .Net 3.5

Fiddler I have never used it. I have just installed, which section I should look into?

Did all the things on the other post you have shared, but nothing on that gave me a solution.

Comment: In fiddler look at the inspector and choose 'raw' for the request - then post that up here :-)

Comment: OPTIONS http://localhost:50596/OrderStatusUpdate.asmx?op=UpdateBooksOrder HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50596
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6